# es6 destructoring (not sure if it's about restructuring)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

So i'm following this tutorial, and i'm getting a strange error.

```
let isDrawing = false
let lastX = 0
let lastY = 0

const draw = function(ev){
    console.log('isDrawing', isDrawing)
    if(!isDrawing){
        return
    }

    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.moveTo(lastX, lastY)
    ctx.lineTo(ev.offsetX, ev.offsetY)
    ctx.stroke()

    //[TODO] destruction doesn't work????
    [lastX, lastY] = [ev.offsetX, ev.offsetY]
    // lastX = ev.offsetX
    // lastY = ev.offsetY
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', draw)
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (ev) => {
  isDrawing = true
  [lastX, lastY] = [ev.offsetX, ev.offsetY]
})
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', () => isDrawing = false)
canvas.addEventListener('mouseout', () => isDrawing = false)
```

in the end of the draw function, if i use the destruction syntax,  i get an error:

> script.js:26 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined
>       at HTMLCanvasElement.draw

Strangely, when i use the same notation in the mousedown event listener, it works without problem.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: btw, the right destructuring assignment is `{ offsetX: lastX, offsetY: lastY } = ev;`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: One can hardly think of a better reason to avoid the anti-semi-colon craziness.

Answer (score 3):

You aren’t using semicolons and have fallen into an ASI trap by starting a line with an opening bracket. It’s parsed as

```
ctx.stroke()[(lastX, lastY)] = [ev.offsetX, ev.offsetY]
```

Comment: thank you, and thank you to @Ry, for pointing to an original question

Comment: That's why you always use semicolons.